# Code says int j=1; debugger says that j=3 (C++)

Tags: c++, integer, compiler-optimization

Honestly the problem is really simple yet I don't know how to fix it. In my program the line says int j=1; yet the debugger says that it equals 3. I even took int j out of the loop to highlight the issue. Is this some weird compiler optimization or something?

Debugger on the left and line highlighted:

[image: Debugger on the left and line highlighted]

I tried to pull j out of the loop to see if anything changed and it didn't. This is for a leetcode problem (Jump Game) where my method was to see if there were any zeroes in the nums array, and if there was a zero, see if there is a value that can jump over it considering the index of that value and the index of the zero. The program worked for most cases but failed if nums = {2, 0, 0}.

Comment: You've not executed that statement yet. After you execute it, `j` will become `1`

Comment: The line the debugger highlights is usually the one that is about to be executed next (but hasn't yet).

Comment: The debugger's line indicator shows you the line that is just about to be executed.  Once you step just past that line, that line has been executed.  Before the line is executed, the space is reserved for `j`, but that `j` has not actually been constructed yet.  It's life time has not yet begun.

Comment: `int size = nums.size() - 1`.  You wil be in for a shock if `nums` is empty.

Comment: When a statement is highlighted in the debugger, that statement has NOT been executed yet - it will be executed on continuing (e.g. stepping to the next statement).   So the value of `j` you see is the value it has/had BEFORE assigning it to `1`  (which may be the result of previously executed code or [if you declare variables without initialising them] an arbitrary value).

Answer (score 1):

> Is this some weird compiler optimization or something?

You've not executed that statement yet. After you execute it, `j` will become `1`

The highlighted line shows what statement is to be executed next. Not what has been executed.

Comment: Thank you, it's obvious now that you mention it. I think it just threw me off that It didn't say j is undefined but j=3 whenever it was in the process of initialization.